# How to find Min(Sum(annotated column)) in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, psql

I have four tables A, B, C and D. each table is associated in a way A -> B -> C -> D by id column.
eg. A.id = B.a_id, B.id = C.b_id and C.id = D.c_id

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
SELECT x.id, min(x.total) as mintotal FROM (SELECT "A"."id",
SUM(("D"."amount" * "D"."quantity")) AS "total", "C"."id" AS "qid" 
FROM "A"  LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON ("A"."id" = "B"."a_id")  LEFT OUTER
JOIN "C" ON ("B"."id" = "C"."c_id")  LEFT OUTER JOIN "D" ON ("C"."id"
= "D"."c_id")  GROUP BY "A"."id", "C"."id")  as x group by x.id  ORDER BY mintotal ASC
```

My equivalent django code

```
query1 = (
    A.objects.all().annotate(
        qid=models.F('b__c__id'),
        total=Sum(models.ExpressionWrapper(
            models.F('b__c__d__amount')*models.F('b__c__d__quantity'),
            output_field=models.DecimalField()
        ))
    ).order_by('total')
)
```

it gives me the inner query output, however when I try to select id and Min(total) again it throws error -

`FieldError: Cannot compute Min('total'): 'total' is an aggregate`

I am new to Django and I am not sure how I can use subquery or exists to get this result. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this SQL is equivalent to what you want

```sql
SELECT
    A.id,
    (
      SELECT
          Sum(D.amount * D.quantity)
      FROM
          D
      JOIN
          C ON C.id = D.c_id
      JOIN
          B ON B.id = C.b_id
      WHERE
          B.a_id = A.id
      GROUP BY C.id
      ORDER BY Sum(D.amount * D.quantity) ASC
      LIMIT 1
        ) as mintotal
FROM
    A;
```

And this can be done using Django's Subquery

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, F

subquery = Subquery(D.objects.values(c__id)
                             .annotate(total=Sum(F('amount') * F('quantity')))
                             .filter(c__b__a__id=OuterRef('id'))
                             .order_by('total')
                             .values('total')[:1])

query1 = A.objects.annotate(mintotal=subquery)
 
# And if you really just want the A.id and mintotal columns:
query1 = A.objects.annotate(mintotal=subquery).values('id', 'mintotal')
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that later. Thank you for your inputs though.